# How to return json response in Laravel using eloquent without \r\n

Tags: php, json, laravel, lumen

I'm using laravel with eloquent and in json response i get \r\n. How can i get rid of them?

```
public function showOneProduct($lng)
{
  return response()->json(Product::where('language', $lng)->get());
}
```

response:

```
[
    {
        "id_produs": 1,
        "produs": " [\r\n        {\r\n        \"product_line\": \"TankTorq Line\",\r\n        \"colors\": [\r\n           \"#D66732\",\r\n           \"#000000\",\r\n           \"#909090\",\r\n           \"#E0E0E0\"\r\n        ],\r\n        \"max_speed\": \"46 km/h\",\r\n        \"range\": \"up to 40 km\",\r\n        \"weight\": \"13.2 kg\",\r\n        \"engine\": \"700W\",\r\n        \"nominalPower\": \"700W\",\r\n        \"nominalContinuousPower\": \"500W\",\r\n        \"line_image\": \"https://worldconnect.me/images/tanktork.png\",\r\n        \"products\": [\r\n           {\r\n              \"name\": \"TK2\",\r\n              \"scooter_features\": [\r\n                 {\r\n                    \"title\": \"Dual motor technology\",\r\n ]",
        "language": "en"
    }
]
```

Comment: You apparently stored `produs` as a json with the line returns, so to get rid of it you'll have to decode it and re-encode it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are saving the `produs` column as JSON,
so you can use [accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) to retrieve it as an array instead of JSON

```
public function getProdusAttribute($value) {
  return json_decode($value,true);
}
```

in case you still want to retrieve as it its with just removing \r\n
you can use [preg_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) , it will do the trick

```
   public function getProdusAttribute($value) {
      return preg_replace("!\r?\n!", "", $value);
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use:

```
public function showOneProduct($lng)
{
  return response()->json( json_decode( json_encode( Product::where('language', $lng)->get() ), true ) );
}
```

Maybe it will helpful